# How to use Origin Types in Azure CDN endpoings?

Tags: azure

I just need to know when to use the Origin Types in Azure CDN endpoints.

I have already created a Web App service and when I create an endpoint, i am presented with a list of Origin Types: Storage,Web App,Cloud service,Custom origin.  If I choose Web App,  I see my Web App.  If I choose Storage,  I see the storage account i created.  My purpose is to have a fast web app by caching all "cachable" assets.

When creating an Azure CDN endpoint,  what or when should I use the following Origin Types :Storage,Web App,Cloud service,Custom origin?

I have not seen any documentation that provides any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

For Azure service like Storage, Web App, Cloud service, you can use that respective origin type, for other public custom name or IP address, you can select `Custom origin`. See the process of [creating a CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-endpoint-how-to).

[image]

Especially, if you host a static website on the Azure storage account. To make your static website files available over your custom domain and HTTPS, see [Using the Azure CDN to access blobs with custom domains over HTTPS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/blobs/storage-https-custom-domain-cdn.md). As a part of this process, you need to point your CDN to the primary static website endpoint as opposed to the primary blob service endpoint.  If so, you can select `primary static website endpoint` in the `custom origin`, see details [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website.md).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I guess I just need to understand what happens when I use the Origin: Type **"Web App"** and select the **_web app_** in the Origin Hostname versus the Origin Type: **"Storage"** and select the **_blob storage_** in the Origin Hostname. see [image](http://prntscr.com/p21vku)

Comment: It means you could cache the content from the (origin server) source web app or blob storage when you select the respective origin type. See [how it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-overview).

Comment: It would be most useful to include a link to the Azure documentation where this is described. In my case, I have Azure Front Door, and I believe I would choose Storage as an origin type, however, I have yet to confirm this anywhere in documentation.